# Erro ao rodar o rebuild no Android Studio

Tags: java, android, gradle, sdk

Olá,

estou tentando desenvolver um app aqui usando o Android Studio, porém ao rodar o rebuild project me gera o erro:

com.android.tools.r8.internal.A10: com.android.tools.r8.graph.F5.asCfCode()

procurei na internet, mas não achei nada referente à esse erro em específico. Acho que não seja nada referente ao código em si, mas à configurações, mais especificamente ao SDK.
Meu build.gradle(:app) está configurado assim:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'

}
android {
    compileSdk 34
    namespace 'com.example.intervalguesser'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile ('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }


    repositories {
        maven {url 'https://maven.google.com'}
        //maven { url 'https://github.com/kshoji/javax.sound.midi-for-Android/raw/master/javax.sound.midi/repository' }
        //maven { url 'https://github.com/kshoji/JFugue-for-Android/raw/master/jfugue-android/snapshot' }
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree (dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.1"
        implementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'

        //implementation 'jp.kshoji:javax-sound-midi:0.0.3:@aar'
        //implementation 'jp.kshoji:jfugue-android:5.0.1.201503:@aar'

    }
}
```

no android/sdk/build-tools tenho duas versões do SDK: 33.0.1 e 34.0.0. No SDK manager está configurado como Android SDK Platform 34. essas configurações estão corretas?